# Could not get response when making POST request from Postman to Node.js (express), MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication, post, postman

I'm facing issues while making simple POST requests from NodeJS server running on localhost. Trying, to POST JSON format data from Postman to NodeJS with express storing data to MySQL. Using the MVC method of going through the Server -> Routes (will format the data) -> Controller (validation & strong to MySQL). Error handling was applied too. but no error showing on Terminal or Postman. I've might miss something on my routes I guess. Appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const errorController = require('./controllers/error');

const app = express();

const PORT = 8080;
const ports = process.env.PORT || PORT;

// MIDDLEWEAR PARSE JSON DATA
app.use(express.json());

// HEADER ACCESS CONTROL, REQUEST, ROUTES
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  );
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Content-Type, Accept, X-Custom-Header, Authorization'
  );
  next();
});

// AUTH
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);

// PAGE NOT FOUND
app.use(errorController.get404);

// SERVER NOT RESPONDING
app.use(errorController.get500);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server started at port ${ports}`);
});
```

Routes/auth.js

```
const express = require('express');

const { body } = require('express-validator');

const router = express.Router();

const User = require('../models/user');

const authController = require('../controllers/auth');

router.post(
  '/signup',
  [
    body('email')
      .isEmail()
      .withMessage('Please enter a valid email.')
      .custom(async (email) => {
        const user = await User.find(email);
        if (user[0].length > 0) {
          return Promise.reject('Email address already exist!');
        }
      })
      .normalizeEmail(),
    body('password').trim().isLength({ min: 7 }),
    body('admin').not().isEmpty(),
  ],
  authController.signup
);

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/auth.js

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const User = require('../models/user');

exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) return;

  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const admin = req.body.admin;

  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    const userDetails = {
      email: email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      admin: admin,
    };

    const results = await User.save(userDetails);

    return res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered!' });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      return err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

error.js

```
// ERROR MIDDLEWARE
exports.get404 = (req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error('Not found');
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
};

exports.get500 = (error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message,
    },
  });
};
```

Models/users.js

```
const db = require('../util/database');

module.exports = class User {
  constructor(email, password, admin) { // TODO: , admin
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.admin = admin;
  }

  static find(email) {
    return db.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email]);
  }

  static save(user) {
    return db.execute('INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [
      user.email,
      user.password,
      user.admin,
    ]);
  }
};
```

Postman

POST -> http://localhost:8080/auth/signup

```
{
    "email": "joe@gmail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "admin": "admin"
}
```

Comment: so what's really the problem here. Does your server never produce any response?

Comment: If so, it feels weird that you have 2 error handlers. Normally there would be just 1. It is generally triggered based on the fact that your controller/one of the previous middlewares threw an error. Then the error middleware checks what kind of error that was and produces an appropriate response. "boomi" module for instance has nice set of errors that already contain the information on what response code should be returned and then you can use that info in your error handler, or make it return error 500 if no specific error code is present in the error

Comment: OP, did you ever resolve this? You could please post an answer with working code? Doing so would help others who read this in future.